# This 5 $\times$ 5 puzzle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Here's the goal: You should walk on every single square, starting with purple.

Rules:

> You can't step on a square twice.
>
> You don't have to return to the purple square.
>
> You can't walk diagonally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It can't be done, tile the pattern as a checkerboard, each move must take us from a White square to a Black square, or a Black square to a White square. There are 13 Black squares and 12 white squares, so the possibility of a path only exists if we start on Black. The Purple square would otherwise be White, so it's not a starting point a path can come from.